# VBS Code for Program Terminator

Tags: vbscript, process, terminator

I would like a VBS code that:

Displays an input box to enter a process name

and can append the process to the code written below:

```
Option Explicit
Dim strComputer, strProcessToKill, objWMIService, colProcess, objProcess

strComputer = "."
strProcessToKill = "notepad.exe"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
  & strComputer _ 
  & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & strProcessToKill & "'")
For Each objProcess in colProcess
  msgbox "... terminating " & objProcess.Name
  objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line

```
strProcessToKill = "notepad.exe"
```

with

```
strProcessToKill = InputBox("Enter process name:")
```

You should add some safety checks, though, in case the user presses `Cancel` or presses `OK` without having anything entered:

```
If IsEmpty(strProcessToKill) Then
  WScript.Echo "User pressed 'Cancel'."
  WScript.Quit 1
ElseIf strProcessToKill = "" Then
  WScript.Echo "Nothing entered."
  WScript.Quit 1
End If
```

Comment: Thanks... I was cracking my head over it.